# database search question PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

my code is this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `cars` WHERE  (color LIKE '%". $key ."%' OR name LIKE '%". $key ."%') AND enabled = 'yes'  ORDER BY  `ID`";
```

database is like this

```
ID     color       name        enabled
----  ------     --------     ---------
1       red        red car       yes
2      blue        blue car      yes
3       brown      brown car     yes
```

r

when i search with the key "red" it returns first field (ID 1) but if i search with "red car" it returns nothing.

how can i search both 2 field ?

thanks

EDIT: i fixed brackets but still i cant get results with more than 1 word keys.

Tried this with no luck

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM  `cars` WHERE  (MATCH (color,name) AGAINST ('$key' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND enabled = 'yes'  ORDER BY  `ID`";
```

EDIT 2: Peter is right. There is no problen in query. weird thing is 
        i use this

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
```

if $_GET['key'] is more than 1 word, $key is returns empty for a reason.

Comment: It goes without saying that you should be careful of sql injection.

Comment: I don't think that this is the cause, but you really should put parentheses around your WHERE criteria. The order in which your ANDs and ORs are resolved may not be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't duplicate your error.  Here's the steps I took

New table

```
CREATE TABLE  `cars` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `color` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then added values

```
INSERT INTO `cars` (`ID`, `color`, `name`, `enabled`) VALUES
  (1,'red','red car','yes')
, (2,'blue','blue car','yes')
, (3,'brown','brown car','yes');
```

Then testing the queries

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM  `cars`
    ->  WHERE (color LIKE '%red%' OR name LIKE '%red%')
    ->    AND enabled = 'yes'
    ->  ORDER BY  `ID`;
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| ID | color | name    | enabled |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | red   | red car | yes     |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM  `cars`
    ->  WHERE (color LIKE '%red car%' OR name LIKE '%red car%')
    ->    AND enabled = 'yes'
    ->  ORDER BY  `ID`;
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| ID | color | name    | enabled |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | red   | red car | yes     |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe look elsewhere for your error

Comment: problem is $key is coming empty is if $_GET['key'] has more than 1 word :S

Answer (score 2):

> "EDIT 2: Peter is right. There is no
>   problen in query. weird thing is i use
>   this
>
> $key = $_GET['key'];
>
> if $_GET['key'] is more than 1 word,
>   $key is returns empty for a reason."

How are you passing in the $_GET? Are you using a form or just typing in your variables

blah.php?key=test+and

NOT

blah.php?key=test and

Comment: yes that was the problem, i am passing it with query load function, than i realized that spaces should be replaced with "+" then i used javascript replace function and it now works perfect thx all

Answer (score 1):

You could use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection:

```
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `cars` WHERE  (color LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?) AND enabled = 'yes'  ORDER BY  `ID`");
$statement->bind_param("s", "%".$key."%");
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `cars` WHERE  (color LIKE '%". $key ."%' OR name LIKE '%". $key ."%') AND enabled = 'yes'  ORDER BY  `ID`";
```

You need to put color and name in brackets, otherwise you might find you will return rows when the field enabled is false.